# Sync Photos without iTunes?

Tags: macos, photos, ios

I really dislike iTunes and would prefer to never use it. The only thing I use it for right now is syncing photos from my iPhone 6 to my OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [iCloud Photo library](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) it'll sync pictures automatically between Mac and iPhone (it does also work with iPad, Apple-tv 4 and iPod Touch 5/6) with iOS 8.1 or newer.

Comment: My phone currently has 6.56 GB of photos and videos, but my iCloud storage space has 4.55GB. Is there a workflow where Photos will move photos from iCloud to my Mac HD (which has 60Gb of photos?)

Comment: 50GB is just 79p/month, well worth it for the backing up of your photos (you can also then optimise storage on your phone and mac for photos), and the automatic syncing, and not having to deal with iTunes.

Comment: @Jonathan. good point. Plus photos are the one thing currently not recoverable if my hd died so having the cloud photos will solve that too...

Comment: I store them on Google-Drive where I pay $2.50/month for 100GB of space, more than enough for most important stuff I keep there (I use a Windows machine).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to import using the native photo app on OSX.

Connect iPhone to Mac via a cable, open photos on Mac, select the import tab in the tab bar or in sidebar.

You may have to give the computer access to your phone.